# Does jQuery AJAX work in modern browsers with PUT and DELETE?

Tags: ajax, rest, jquery

The [jQuery AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has a `type` parameter that allows to specify the method for an async call (`GET`/`POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE`); documentation states that:

> The type of
>   request to make ("POST" or "GET"),
>   default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP
>   request methods, such as PUT and
>   DELETE, can also be used here, **but
>   they are not supported by all
>   browsers.**

What does this mean for modern browsers? Can I count on jQuery AJAX to make fully RESTful calls, which rely on the `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. `$.ajax` makes the dirty work to allow PUT and DELETE.

Here you'll find more info: [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Comment: Beat me to it! Exactly where I was going to link to, too!

Comment: their documentation states, "The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers." -- under 'type' on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 10):

I know it's an old question, but I keep on coming here when searching for the browsers HTTP methods support. I never found anything saying exactly which browser supports which call.  The link provided is not clear on it too.

Because of that sentence in `jQuery` manual (*they are not supported by all browsers*), I've stayed clear for a while of `PUT` and `DELETE` and tried to limit myself to `GET` and `POST`. However, today I decided to run some tests with IE 6 for a rest API I'm developing and I didn't have any problems to use also `DELETE`.

If it works in IE6, crappy 2001 technology, it is pretty much likely that it will work everywhere and that sentence on jQuery manual is pretty much obsolete.

I will update this post in the future with further tests. If anyone knows of a browser not supporting ajax calls for `PUT` and `DELETE`, I would like to hear.

Comment: Hi, I have searched for more information on this, I understand DELETE is safe to use, have you had any experience with PUT ?

Comment: @inf3rno, any updates? I'm using IE9 and jquery 2.0.3... Also doesn't work for both DELETE & PUT

Comment: I don't know, I am developing on IE10+ now (because of CORS support).

Comment: @inf3no/user2503775- By all accounts PUT/DELETE *do* work on IE8/9. As far as I can tell the only HTTP method IE8 lacks native support for is PATCH. (See [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2152)).